# How much free space does Windows really need to be performant?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ntfs

We have a virtualized file server here whose data resides on a SAN - performance through the SAN is plentiful.
But now the 2TB disk on the virtualized Windows 2012R2 file server is almost full since several weeks (30GB Free) and we discuss internally how much free space Windows really needs to be performant.
For ages there has been a recommendation that NTFS needs about 10% free space - can this be measured so that I have an argument for increasing or splitting the drive?

Best regards!

Comment: No real data here, but using defrag analyze it shows you MFT among other things, if there is not enough space available the MFT get's fragmented, and that has many times had a huge performance impact on machines for me.
Only way to recover from that is to recreate the filesystem.

Comment: If it's not c part enable deduplication in example

Comment: I have checked the defragmentation.
Here we were at over 85% fragmentation level.
The deduplication is already active here.
I'll see if I can find any other processes that I can use for argumentation.